# Galois group of $f(x)=x^5+2x+1\in\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

consider $f(x)=x^5+2x+1\in\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$,what is the splitting field of $f$ and its Galois group?

I know it is a Galois extension. But i do not know the degree of the extension for i have no idea of the root of $f$,
the answer is the cyclic group of order 5.

any idea will be helpful!

Comment: Since $f$ doesn't have root in $\Bbb Z_3$, it is reducible iff an irreducible monic quadratic polynomial divides it. Without any further idea, I'd list all these quadratics and see if they divide $f$..

Comment: yes, we can prove that $f$ is irreducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is irreducible then $\Bbb{F}_3[x]/(f)$ is a field of $3^5$ elements. Since all fields of $3^5$ elements are isomorphic, adjoining any root of $f$ yields the same field (up to isomorphism) and hence this field is a splitting field of $f$, and so
$$|\operatorname{Gal}(f)|=[\Bbb{F}_3[x]/(f):\Bbb{F}_3]=5.$$
Every group of order $5$ is cyclic.

Comment: if $\alpha \beta$are roots of $f$, then $\mathbb{F}_3[\alpha]$ is isomorphism to  $\mathbb{F}_3[\beta]$.but it does not mean that $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_3[\beta]$.

Comment: @yufenglu Actually, it does; if $\alpha\notin\Bbb{F}_3[\beta]$ then $\Bbb{F}_3[\alpha,\beta]$ is a field containing two distinct subfields of $3^5$ elements. But any element of a field of $3^5$ elements satisfies $x^{3^5}=x$, so
$$\Bbb{F}_3[\alpha]=\{x\in\Bbb{F}_3[\alpha,\beta]:\ x^{3^5}=x\}=\Bbb{F}_3[\beta],$$
because any field contains at most $3^5$ elements satisfying $x^{3^5}=x$.

Comment: i got the point. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $f$ is irriducible then you can consider the field exstension $F'=\Bbb Z_3[x]/I$, where $I:=(f(x))$, the ideal generated by $f$. Now for the theorem of Kronecker exist a root $\alpha$ of $f$  ( $\alpha:= x+I$). The elements of $F'$ are $$F'=\{a+b\alpha+c\alpha ^2+d\alpha ^3+e\alpha ^4 : a,b,c,d,e \in \Bbb Z_3[x]\}.$$ Using the euclidean division we obtain: $$x^5+2x+1=(x^4+\alpha x^3+\alpha ^2x^2+\alpha ^3x+(2+\alpha ^4))(x-\alpha ).$$ Now yuo can prove that the other roots belong to $F'$. This show that $F'$ is the splitting field of $f$ and that $G(F'/F)=Z_5$.

Comment: what is the root of $(x^5+2x+1)/(x-\alpha)$?

Comment: @yufenglu use the fact that $\alpha ^5+2\alpha+1=0$

Comment: what are the other  roots besides the $\alpha$?